# Why do basil leaves turn black?

Tags: biochemistry, plant-physiology

I notice that when I buy basil it is fresh and green in the store, but when I take it home it wilts and turns black within 24 hours.

Why does it do this?

Comment: That seems pretty fast to me. How is it stored in the store and how do you store it at home? Specifically, is it frozen at any point or bashed around during transport at all?

Comment: collected green leaves sometimes turned black. Maybe it is the same process like cut apple turns black.

Comment: I've seen some fig latexes often turn red or black.